# Can a pom file uploaded to a remote repository via mvn deploy have a classifier in its name?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, hudson, maven-3

Can a pom file uploaded to a remote repository via mvn deploy have a classifier in its name?

For example, if I have artifacts `Webapp-1.0.war` and `Webapp-1.0-CLASSIFIER.war` can I easily have `Webapp-1.0.pom` and `Webapp-1.0-CLASSIFIER.pom`?

I'd like to be able to deploy artifacts with multiple classifiers to the same repository, but the `mvn deploy` goal always fails because it's trying to upload a pom that's already there.

I don't want to use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` if I can avoid it because I don't want to unnecessarily complicate my CI build, i.e., having to specify file/url as configuration parameters because the file and url will change depending on whether I'm deploying a snapshot/release version.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the understanding of Maven. If you produce an artifact which has an classifier it means having a pom which describes creating the artifact with the classifier as well as an artifact without an classifier. In other words your problem can be solved by having a single pom file. Furthermore you can deploy an artifact and several artifacts with classifiers with a single call to the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) call like the following:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
-DgroupId=com.soebes.test
-DartifactId=x1
-Dversion=2.7.5-SNAPSHOT
-Dfile=TheMainArtifact.jar
-Dclassifiers=first,second
-Dfiles=firstFile,secondFile
-Dtypes=zip,xml
-DrepositoryId=RepositoryId 
-Durl=URLOfTheRepository
```

With the above (into a single line) you can deploy several files with a single deploy command without changing the configuration of Neuxs or any other repository manager to allow redeploying (wrong way!).

Comment: I agree with you and I've considered this plugin -- what stopped me from using it is that I don't want to have to specify version numbers, repositories, etc., every time my CI server does a build. Do you have any suggestions for parameterizing version/repository id/url?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before too.  As far as I know, classified POMs aren't allowed.

The trick is to configure the remote repo to allow the POM to be updated while not allowing redeploy of other artifacts.

In Nexus, this is done through Repository Targets.  The pattern to match POMs in a repository is `.*/(?!.*\.pom).*`.  The target gets linked to Privileges, which may be assigned to Roles, which are then assigned to Users.  (Memory is a little fuzzy here, I got this working and then decided to use `deploy:deploy-file` instead.)

Comment: Never configure a Nexus a allow redeploying of artifacts, cause if you allow such thing you will contradict the basic idea of Maven artifacts. A single deployment means only a single one. Never a second one with the same coordinates (GAV) to prevent overwriting the previous.

Comment: With Nexus, if you have redeploy turned off (agree, the right way to have things set up) then you cannot use deploy:deploy to add a classified artifact, even if the classified one doesn't yet exist.  As the OP said, it will fail due to the POM not being updateable.  In the scenario I tested, the POM was never changing, but I couldn't find a way to make the `deploy` not include the POM.  The repository target solved this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a classified pom. For every groupId + artifactId + version there's exactly one pom, and this pom is also used for the attached/classified artifacts. So this means that for instance that the main artifact and all the attached artifacts have the same dependencies.
Most used attached artifacts are `javadoc` and `sources`, for which this makes perfectly sense.

Comment: And my current process, using `deploy` works fine in this scenario. What it doesn't help is allowing me to easily add a WAR with a classifier that's from a separate build/profile.

Comment: Maybe you've asked the wrong question. If your project generated a main-war and a custom-war (which use the same pom.xml), you should add multiple execution-block (http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) within the maven-war-plugin. The custom war then should use http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#classifier . In general avoid profiles, I think your usecase doesn't match the intended usage of profiles.